# Is $\{(\epsilon + \cos(x))^{2k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ a family of good kernels?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

> Show that for any $0<\delta<\pi$,
>   $$\lim_{k\to \infty} c_k\int_{\delta<|x|<\pi} \left(\epsilon + \cos(x)\right)^{2k} dx = 0 $$ 
>   where $\epsilon >0$ is some small number (for example, $0.01$) and $c_k$ is **chosen** so that
>   $$\frac{c_k}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(\epsilon + \cos(x)\right)^k dx = 1$$

My ultimate goal is to show that trigonometric polynomial is dense. I understand that Fejer kernels is good kernels and they are trigonometric polynomials. But I am curious if there is a simpler construction.

In terms of what I am trying to prove here, I feel like the picture is clear. More specifically, when you raise $\epsilon + \cos(x)$ to the $2k$-th power, most of it will vanish since they have absolute value less than $1$. But I am having trouble coming up with a rigorous proof.

Unwrapping the definition, for any $\alpha>0$, we want to find $K$ such that whenver $k>K$, we have
$$c_k \int_{\delta<|x|<\pi} (\epsilon + \cos(x))^{2k} dx  < \alpha$$

Then the best thing I have is something like "Given  $\alpha$ and $\delta$, we can always raise the power enough times so that the $\epsilon + \cos(x)$ is small enough, and thus the whole integral gets small enough". I am not sure if this is rigorous enough though.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The limit in the problem statement should be $k\to\infty$, right?

Comment: @NicholasStull Yes, you are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the double approximation
$$ \forall x\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right],\qquad 1-\frac{x^2}{2}\leq\cos(x)\leq e^{-x^2/2}$$
is everything we need. By approximating $\varepsilon+\cos(x)$ with $(1+\varepsilon)\,e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(1+\varepsilon)}} $ we have that
$$ \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\left(\varepsilon+\cos x\right)^{2k}\,dx \approx (1+\varepsilon)^{2k}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left(-\frac{kx^2}{1+\varepsilon}\right)\,dx = (1+\varepsilon)^{2k+\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k}} $$
and the main contribute to the LHS is concentrated in a smaller and smaller neighbourhood of zero as $k\to +\infty$. That happens every time we consider a kernel strongly resembling a Gaussian kernel, since:
$$ \forall K>0,\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-K x^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{K}},\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}x\cdot e^{-K x^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2K}.$$

Comment: why did you choose this double approximation, what is the intuition behind it?